# После открытия activity, поднимается listview

Tags: java, android, activity, android-layout

Привет всем.
Может кто-то сталкивался со следующей проблемой или знает как решить следующее.
После открытия activity, сразу отображается listview, т.е. activity отображается не сверху. Если высота layout помещается на экран, то показывает как обычно, как надо. Но если listview заполнен несколькими элементами, то activity автоматом пролистывается до listview.

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<ScrollView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@color/mainBackground"
    android:layout_below="@id/tool_bar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlTopMaterialCard"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/tvProductionName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text=""/>

            <TextView
                fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:id="@+id/tvCountry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvProductionName"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textColor="@color/symbol_black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text=""
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvCountry"
                android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:text="@string/descriptionDetails"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/rlTopMaterialCard"
            android:id="@+id/sliderImages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            custom:pager_animation="Default"
            custom:auto_cycle="true"
            custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
            custom:pager_animation_span="1100"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@color/gray"/>

        <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
            android:layout_below="@+id/sliderImages"
            android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            custom:selected_color="#0095BF"
            custom:unselected_color="#55333333"
            custom:shape="oval"
            custom:selected_padding_left="5dp"
            custom:selected_padding_right="5dp"
            custom:unselected_padding_left="5dp"
            custom:unselected_padding_right="5dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            custom:selected_width="6dp"
            custom:selected_height="6dp"
            custom:unselected_width="6dp"
            custom:unselected_height="6dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/custom_indicator"
            android:id="@+id/llShopText"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                android:id="@+id/tvShop"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="@string/shops"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate
            android:layout_below="@+id/llShopText"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/pbLoadingShops"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_below="@+id/llShopText"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/lvShops"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true">
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Высота listview рассчитывается следующим образом.

```
if (shopsAdapter.getCount() > 0)
{
    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(lvShops.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    float totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < shopsAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = shopsAdapter.getView(i, null, lvShops);
        if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup) {
            listItem.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = lvShops.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = (int) (totalHeight + (lvShops.getDividerHeight() * (lvShops.getCount() - 1)));
    lvShops.setLayoutParams(params);
    lvShops.requestLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ScroolView** не предназначена для работы с **ListView** внутри.

В вашем случае самым изящным решением будет:

1) Перенос всего что вне **ListView** в его **Header** методом **addHeader(View v)**.

2) Т.к. **ScroolView** уже не будет нужен, его надо убрать.

Так вам не надо будет изощряться с измерением высоты **ListView** плюс повысится производительность, т.к. **Header** это, технически, элемент **ListView**.

Comment: А **Header** пролистываться будет? я с этим никогда не сталкивался

Comment: Не должен. Этот глюк скорее всего вызван наличием ListView  в ScroolView. Предложенный в ответе способ - это как если просто в ListView  добавить ещё один элемент.